# Why did these carcasses randomly appear in mope.io?

Tags: mope.io

I was playing mope.io when suddenly these two carcasses popped up in the dessert.

[image: The first corpse which I couldn't identify]

The first carcass, a shark/whale/seal carcass suddenly appeared when I was wandering around.

[image: The octopus corpse]

This was the second carcass, a squid/octopus carcass that popped up in the middle of the desert, nowhere near the ocean.

Why did they suddenly pop up in the middle of the dessert? Is this a glitch?